# line buttons in one line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How can I perfectly align 4 Buttons in one line with a margin / padding between each button.

So far I did create this layout, but it is not perfeclty aligned:

Further I Need to have a text under each button which are aligned aswell.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your buttons must be aligned vertical or horizontal?, you need to add the `android:orientation="vertical"` attribute to your LinearLayout

Comment: Please share your desired layout image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: would this Show 4 button for all devices?

Comment: Yes, if you dont set a fixed width, all the buttons will be visible on all screen sizes with no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the attribute android:gravity="center" or "left" or "right" for your layout.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For horizontally align 4 Buttons in one line with a margin / padding between each button.

Please try below code:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text 1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text 2"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Button3"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text 3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="Button4"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text 4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Output for above code in different devices:

For Device 1

[image]

For Device 2

[image]